# Postgres how can I select just one row from a One -to-Many relationship between keys

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT dfile.id
FROM dcmstudy_t dstud
INNER JOIN dcmseries_t dser ON dstud.id = dser.dcmstudy_id
INNER JOIN dcmfile_t dfile ON dser.id = dfile.dcmseries_id
INNER JOIN finst_t fi ON dfile.id = fi.file_id
INNER JOIN store s ON s.id = fi.store_id
WHERE dser.id in (69823713)
```

when given the ID number in the `WHERE` clause, this query will return ~300 rows of `dfile.id`. The problem I have is I just need one `dfile.id` for each `dser.id` in the WHERE clause. I know if I was just providing one `dser.id` then I could just LIMIT 1, but I need to provide many `dser.id` in the `WHERE` clause and have each produce just one `dfile.id`. In the end I want to be able to produce a table that contains many different `dser.id` with each corresponding to one `dfile.id`. It is probably good to mention the relationship between `dser.id` and `dfile.id` is one to many, many `dfile.id` to one single `dser.id`. Any suggestions?

UPDATE

After looking over all your suggestions I came up with the following query that solved my problem.

```
SELECT dser.id,s.oname,Min(dfile.id) as FileID
FROM dcmstudy_t dstud
INNER JOIN dcmseries_t dser ON dstud.id = dser.dcmstudy_id
INNER JOIN dcmfile_t dfile ON dser.id = dfile.dcmseries_id
INNER JOIN finst_t fi ON dfile.id = fi.file_id
INNER JOIN store s ON s.id = fi.store_id
WHERE dser.id in (69823713,69644830,63763440)
group by dser.id,s.oname
```

Thanks everyone for the input.

Comment: for `dfile.id` is there any criteria or any one you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the query mentioned in the question is correct, You can use `distinct on` clause of `PostgreSQL` as mentioned below:

Try this :

```
SELECT distinct on (dser.id)  dfile.id 
FROM dcmstudy_t dstud
INNER JOIN dcmseries_t dser ON dstud.id = dser.dcmstudy_id
INNER JOIN dcmfile_t dfile ON dser.id = dfile.dcmseries_id
INNER JOIN finst_t fi ON dfile.id = fi.file_id
INNER JOIN store s ON s.id = fi.store_id
WHERE dser.id in (69823713) 
order by dser.id, dfile.id
```

above query will return the first `dfile.id`.